# Will blacklisting a binary in abrt config still generate a core dump?

Tags: centos, centos7

On a shared CentOs 7.5, whenever one of my c++ apps crash abrt-hook-cpp process kicks in and take 100% cpu on one core. After few crashes the server crawls to a halt.

There are different ways of excluding an application from abrtd as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sect-abrt-configuration-abrt) and [here](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/CCpp-plugin). E.g. BlackList, IgnoredPaths.

If I do that will I still get a good old core dump?

core pattern is:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e %P %I %h
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find abrt at all useful, disabling it is unproductive. Fixing the crashes addresses the root cause.

CCpp hook configuration, including IgnorePaths, AllowedGroups, or MakeCompatCore, will *not* disable abrt's hook.  The hook is installed with the abrt-ccpp.service unit, from the abrt-addon-ccpp package. Remove that package to revert to a classic core_pattern.  (MakeCompatCore saves a copy in the core_pattern file name, but in addition to abrt's processing.)

Concurrency is controlled by /usr/sbin/abrt-install-ccpp-hook which sets /proc/sys/kernel/core_pipe_limit to 4. Set this to 1 if your host cannot handle 4 at once.

Comment: Thanks. Crashes are not due to one specific reason, sporadic over months and mostly due peer apps sending malformed data. For performance reasons we don't want to validate everything and would rather not have try/catch everywhere either. My thinking what that above keys will tell abrt / abrt-hook-cpp to not to handle the specific app, not disable abrt-hook-cpp. Especially "IgnorePaths" in /etc/abrt/plugins/CCpp.conf seem to do this.

Comment: Minimal sanity checking so your program does not crash will have less of a performance hit than unplanned downtime and recovery when it does crash. Do what you like with core dumps, but they could be improving that software.